# Oauthcpp: Undefined reference to OAuth

Tags: c++, twitter-api, oauth

Estoy usando el siguiente código. El cual se puede obtener de [aqui](https://github.com/sirikata/liboauthcpp).

Busco poder hacer un twitter desde un programa, estoy usando codeblocks en SO raspbian. Mas abajo están los errores que me marca al compilar.

También seguí las instrucciones mostradas utilizando cmake y me salen archivos ejecutables (que creo que uno de ellos utiliza este código) y no obtengo nada.

Agradecería que me pudieran orientar para poder utilizar esta librería de forma correcta

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <liboauthcpp/liboauthcpp.h>

 /* These are input settings that make this demo actually work -- you need to get
  * these, e.g. by referring to the Twitter documentation and by registering an
  * application with them. Here we have examples from Twitter. If you
  * don't enter any, you'll be prompted to enter them at runtime.
  */
 std::string consumer_key = ""; // Key from Twitter
 std::string consumer_secret = ""; // Secret from Twitter
 std::string request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
 std::string request_token_query_args = "oauth_callback=oob";
 std::string authorize_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
 std::string access_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";


std::string getUserString(std::string prompt) {
std::cout << prompt << " ";

std::string res;
std::cin >> res;
std::cout << std::endl;
return res;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
if (argc > 1 && std::string(argv[1]) == std::string("--debug"))
    OAuth::SetLogLevel(OAuth::LogLevelDebug);

// Initialization
if (consumer_key.empty()) consumer_key = getUserString("Enter consumer key:");
if (consumer_secret.empty()) consumer_secret = getUserString("Enter consumer secret:");
OAuth::Consumer consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret);
OAuth::Client oauth(&consumer);

// Step 1: Get a request token. This is a temporary token that is used for
// having the user authorize an access token and to sign the request to
// obtain said access token.
std::string base_request_token_url = request_token_url + (request_token_query_args.empty() ? std::string("") : (std::string("?")+request_token_query_args) );
std::string oAuthQueryString =
    oauth.getURLQueryString( OAuth::Http::Get, base_request_token_url);

std::cout << "Enter the following in your browser to get the request token: " << std::endl;
// Note that getting the query string includes the arguments we
// passed in, so we don't need to include request_token_query_args
// again.
std::cout << request_token_url << "?" << oAuthQueryString << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;

// Extract the token and token_secret from the response
std::string request_token_resp = getUserString("Enter the response:");
// This time we pass the response directly and have the library do the
// parsing (see next extractToken call for alternative)
OAuth::Token request_token = OAuth::Token::extract( request_token_resp );

// Get access token and secret from OAuth object
std::cout << "Request Token:" << std::endl;
std::cout << "    - oauth_token        = " << request_token.key() << std::endl;
std::cout << "    - oauth_token_secret = " << request_token.secret() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;

// Step 2: Redirect to the provider. Since this is a CLI script we
// do not redirect. In a web application you would redirect the
// user to the URL below.
std::cout << "Go to the following link in your browser to authorize this application on a user's account:" << std::endl;
std::cout << authorize_url << "?oauth_token=" << request_token.key() << std::endl;

// After the user has granted access to you, the consumer, the
// provider will redirect you to whatever URL you have told them
// to redirect to. You can usually define this in the
// oauth_callback argument as well.
std::string pin = getUserString("What is the PIN?");
request_token.setPin(pin);

// Step 3: Once the consumer has redirected the user back to the
// oauth_callback URL you can request the access token the user
// has approved. You use the request token to sign this
// request. After this is done you throw away the request token
// and use the access token returned. You should store the oauth
// token and token secret somewhere safe, like a database, for
// future use.
oauth = OAuth::Client(&consumer, &request_token);
// Note that we explicitly specify an empty body here (it's a GET) so we can
// also specify to include the oauth_verifier parameter
oAuthQueryString = oauth.getURLQueryString( OAuth::Http::Get, access_token_url, std::string( "" ), true );
std::cout << "Enter the following in your browser to get the final access token & secret: " << std::endl;
std::cout << access_token_url << "?" << oAuthQueryString;
std::cout << std::endl;

// Once they've come back from the browser, extract the token and token_secret from the response
std::string access_token_resp = getUserString("Enter the response:");
// On this extractToken, we do the parsing ourselves (via the library) so we
// can extract additional keys that are sent back, in the case of twitter,
// the screen_name
OAuth::KeyValuePairs access_token_resp_data = OAuth::ParseKeyValuePairs(access_token_resp);
OAuth::Token access_token = OAuth::Token::extract( access_token_resp_data );

std::cout << "Access token:" << std::endl;
std::cout << "    - oauth_token        = " << access_token.key() << std::endl;
std::cout << "    - oauth_token_secret = " << access_token.secret() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "You may now access protected resources using the access tokens above." << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;

std::pair<OAuth::KeyValuePairs::iterator, OAuth::KeyValuePairs::iterator> screen_name_its = access_token_resp_data.equal_range("screen_name");
for(OAuth::KeyValuePairs::iterator it = screen_name_its.first; it != screen_name_its.second; it++)
    std::cout << "Also extracted screen name from access token response: " << it->second << std::endl;

// E.g., to use the access token, you'd create a new OAuth using
// it, discarding the request_token:
// oauth = OAuth::Client(&consumer, &access_token);

return 0;
}
```

Los errores que me da son:

```
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `OAuth::SetLogLevel(OAuth::_LogLevel)'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `OAuth::Consumer::Consumer(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `OAuth::Client::Client(OAuth::Consumer const*)'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:42: undefined reference to `OAuth::Client::getURLQueryString(OAuth::Http::_RequestType, std::string const&, std::string const&, bool) const'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:55: undefined reference to `OAuth::Token::extract(std::string const&)'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:83: undefined reference to `OAuth::Client::Client(OAuth::Consumer const*, OAuth::Token const*)'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:83: undefined reference to `OAuth::Client::~Client()'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:86: undefined reference to `OAuth::Client::getURLQueryString(OAuth::Http::_RequestType, std::string const&, std::string const&, bool) const'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:96: undefined reference to `OAuth::ParseKeyValuePairs(std::string const&)'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:97: undefined reference to `OAuth::Token::extract(std::multimap<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&)'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `OAuth::Client::~Client()'
 /home/pi/Documents/C++/twitter3/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `OAuth::Client::~Client()'
```

Comment: ¿Qué IDE estás usando?

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta que no has configurado los directorios de inclusión y/o que no has incluido en el proyecto todos los archivos de código **pero sólo son conjeturas pues no se qué IDE estás usando**.

Comment: El IDE es codeblocks, y trabajo en SO raspbian (raspberry pi). Es la primera vez que estoy sacando codigos de github, asi que lo mas seguro es que este acomodando mal o me estan faltando archivos

Comment: Se que tengo que utilizar CMAKE (ya lo hice) pero no me ha funcionado, no se si tenga que acomodar los archivos en diferentes lugares. Estoy trabajando en una màquina linux.

Comment: No creo que tenga que ver con CMAKE, yo uso esta librería en MSVC y no usé CMAKE para nada. Eso si: tuve que configurar el proyecto para que tuviera acceso a las carpetas con el código fuente ¿has hecho lo mismo en Code::Blocks?

Comment: No he hecho eso, lo que hice fue mandar las librerias a las carpetas generales

Comment: Si no es mucha molestia, podrías mostrarme como le diste acceso a las carpetas? y si tienes un codigo de ejemplo tambien ayudaría.